# Repackage RPM with kernel

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel, package-management, rpm

I am tinkering with CentOS 5.4 and upgrading the kernel to the latest 2.6.18 build 402.  What I need to do is to rebuild the initrd to include a modified init script, then repackage it all into an RPM I can use to deploy.

I have the initrd rebuilt and the system boots fine using it, but I cannot find out how to repackage the kernel rpm to include that new initrd.  Kernel is not rebuilt and, unless I have to, I'd prefer not to do so.

Comment: The `initrd` should be generated at install time, not included in the package.

Comment: No, it's in the rpm: `rpm -qlp kernel-2.6.18-402.el5.i686.rpm | grep initrd` gives me the output `/boot/initrd-2.6.18-402.el5.img`

Comment: @Jon, take a look at this. Could be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354782/unpacking-an-rpm-file-and-repacking-it - Cheers

Comment: As it turns out, there _is_ a spec file to generate an rpm to separately distribute the modified initrd.  And... one of our builds team found it!  So, we install the kernel as it is distributed, then drop the modified initrd on top and update the grub.conf.  Not as slick as what I'd been thinking, but it's now a documented process, the spec file will go into version control and all shall be right with the gods.

Comment: .. and neither the kernel RPM nor this third-party RPM conflict over ownership of the file?  you will get issues otherwise.

Comment: We rename the initrd file prior to inclusion in our rpm.  So we have the kernel's version, sitting pristine and untouched, plus ours.